# How to make `NestedScrollView` only scroll its body when necessary

Tags: flutter

I'm using `NestedScrollView.headerSliverBuilder` property to reproduce the same iOS behavior of collapsing the page title when scrolling the screen content, like the GIF below illustrate

[image]

And it's working really good so far. The problem is that, when the screen content is lower than the screen bounds, I would like to block the `NestedScrollView` body scroll, since in theory it wouldn't be necessary to scroll because all the content is visible (just like the GIF example).

Here's the code I'm using in the GIF example:

```dart
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return CupertinoPageScaffold(
      child: NestedScrollView(
        headerSliverBuilder: (context, innerBoxIsScrolled) => [
          SliverOverlapAbsorber(
            handle: NestedScrollView.sliverOverlapAbsorberHandleFor(context),
            sliver: SliverSafeArea(
              top: false,
              bottom: false,
              sliver: CupertinoSliverNavigationBar(largeTitle: Text('Page Title')),
            ),
          ),
        ],
        body: Material(
          child: SafeArea(
            top: false,
            child: Center(child: Container(color: Colors.red, height: 50)),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: On windows / web (with `MaterialApp(home: CupertinoPageScaffold(...`) gives the same behavior as in the gif, it might be a routing issue.

Comment: @SrPanda Yeah, but the goal is to block the scrolling in the GIF, because based on the body content height, it's not necessary to scroll the page

Comment: My bad, i misunderstood, but if the goal is just to block the scroll you can use [NeverScrollableScrollPhysics](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/NeverScrollableScrollPhysics-class.html) to disable it.

Comment: @SrPanda The problem is that I don't know when the content of the screen is scrollable and when it isn't. I would have to calculate the screen content to be able to use `NeverScrollableScrollPhysics` or not. I was hoping that it would have a better solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `CustomScrollView` instead of `NestedScrollView`:

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return CupertinoPageScaffold(
      child: CustomScrollView(
        slivers: [
          const SliverSafeArea(
            top: false,
            bottom: false,
            sliver:
                CupertinoSliverNavigationBar(largeTitle: Text('Page Title')),
          ),
          SliverToBoxAdapter(
            child: Material(
              child: SafeArea(
                top: false,
                child: Center(child: Container(color: Colors.red, height: 50)),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: This solution is almost perfect, thanks for that! I'm just facing a strange behavior when the body is scrollable. It seems that when scrolling the body, the app bar doesn't change to "compact" state, but scrolling the app bar instead the body content does compact it. See the video: https://youtu.be/03U6-cwzL0o. Seems an issue of scroll priority?

Comment: No I think you are using a listview inside the SliverToBoxadapter. For none scrollable widgets you should use SliverToBoxadapter, but for scrollable widgets like ListView, you should use Sliver equivalent of that widget which is SliverList instead of ListView or SliverGrid instead of GridView, see https://docs.flutter.dev/ui/advanced/slivers

Comment: If this helps you, please consider accepting my answer, or if you need more help, let me know :)

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend to stick with the builtin behaviors
To reproduce this kind of reducing app bar with better animation, fluidity and integrated ClampingScroll you could use a `CustomScrollView` with a `SliverAppBar`.

Feel free to change the itemCount to see the behavior when its scrolling, also change the `FlexibleSpaceBar` to reproduce the AppBar you want. You can add background image and more.

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: CustomScrollView(
        slivers: <Widget>[
          SliverAppBar(
            pinned: true,
            floating: true,
            snap: true,
            expandedHeight: 200.0,
            flexibleSpace: FlexibleSpaceBar(
              title: Text("Twitter-like AppBar"),
            ),
          ),
          SliverList(
            delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate(
              childCount: 3,
              (context, index) => ListTile(
                title: Text('Item #${index}'),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```